# Modelling a Call Center in Java (multithreading approach)

Tags: java, object-oriented, multithreading, interview-questions

I wanted to give a shot to **Modelling a Call Center** from **Cracking the Coding Interview**. The problem statement is as follows:

> You have a call center with three levels of employees: Respondent, Manager, Director. An incoming phone call must be allocated to a respondent who is free. If the respondent cannot handle the call, they must escalate it to a manager. If the manager is not free or not able to handle it, the call should be escalated to a director.

Here is my implementation in Java, which accepts calls from the command line in the form of: `level,duration`. For example entering: `0,25` represents a call that can be handled by a Respondant (level 0) and that will take 25 seconds to complete.

The code should be easy to just copy / paste to an IDE or just compile with `javac` in case you want to play with it in your local environment. Simply save it in `CallCenter.java` in global package and you are good to go.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

public class CallCenter {

    static BlockingQueue<Call> respondantQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(20);
    static BlockingQueue<Call> directorQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(20);

    static List<Manager> managers = Arrays.asList(new Manager("Manager - 1"), new Manager("Manager - 2"));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new CallCenter().operate();
    }

    void operate() throws InterruptedException {
        Arrays.asList(new Respondant("Respondant - 1"), new Respondant("Respondant - 2"));
        Arrays.asList(new Director("The Director"));

        System.out.println("Enter values representing call in the format: 0,25.");
        System.out.println("First value is level required, second value is call duration.");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String s = scanner.nextLine();
            if ("q".equals(s)) {
                break;
            }
            String[] split = s.split(",");
            Call call = new Call(parseInt(split[0]), parseInt(split[1]));
            dispatchCall(call);
        }
        scanner.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void dispatchCall(Call call) throws InterruptedException {
        respondantQueue.put(call);
    }
}

class Call {

    static int idCounter = 0;

    int id;
    int durationInSeconds;
    int level;

    public Call(int level, int durationInSeconds) {
        this.level = level;
        this.durationInSeconds = durationInSeconds;
        this.id = idCounter++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Call{" + "id=" + id + ", duration(sec)=" + durationInSeconds + ", level=" + level + '}';
    }
}

class Respondant {
    String name;

    public Respondant(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Call call = CallCenter.respondantQueue.take();
                    if (call.level == 0) {
                        System.out.println(name + " handling call: " + call);
                        Thread.sleep(call.durationInSeconds * 1000);
                    } else {
                        boolean managerHandled = false;
                        for (Manager manager : CallCenter.managers) {
                            if (!manager.isBusy) {
                                manager.acceptCall(call);
                                managerHandled = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!managerHandled) {
                            CallCenter.directorQueue.put(call);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

class Manager {
    String name;
    volatile boolean isBusy = false;

    public Manager(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void acceptCall(Call call) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                isBusy = true;
                if (call.level == 1) {
                    System.out.println(name + " handling call: " + call);
                    Thread.sleep(call.durationInSeconds * 1000);
                } else {
                    CallCenter.directorQueue.put(call);
                }
                isBusy = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        }).start();
    }
}

class Director {
    String name;

    public Director(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Call call = CallCenter.directorQueue.take();
                    System.out.println(name + " handling call: " + call);
                    Thread.sleep(call.durationInSeconds * 1000 / 4); // Director handles calls 4 times faster!
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

A sample run for me is as follows:

```
Enter values representing call in the format: 0,25.
First value is level required, second value is call duration.
0,5
Respondant - 1 handling call: Call{id=0, duration(sec)=5, level=0}
0,5
Respondant - 2 handling call: Call{id=1, duration(sec)=5, level=0}
1,5
Manager - 1 handling call: Call{id=2, duration(sec)=5, level=1}
1,5
Manager - 2 handling call: Call{id=3, duration(sec)=5, level=1}
1,5
The Director handling call: Call{id=4, duration(sec)=5, level=1}
```

Comment: I won't do a proper review, but it seems to make more sense to use a thread pool than start a new thread every time. It also doesn't make much sense for the thread to be created in the different classes, so a thread pool would solve that. I'd probably also create an interface with acceptCall/canHandle methods as well.

Comment: @ChrisSchneider I am creating a new thread for every instance of `Respondent` and `Director` which is required and cannot be replaced by a thread pool I think. For `Manager` class, hmm maybe. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give you a full review, because the code complexity is too high..

## Little Typo

Respond**e**nt instead of Respond**a**nt.

## You did not Implement the Task

> If the respondent cannot handle the call, they must escalate it to a manager.

The `Respondent` handles his call:

> ```java
> if (call.level == 0) {
>  System.out.println(name + " handling call: " + call);
>  Thread.sleep(call.durationInSeconds * 1000);
> }
> ```

When the call is of level `0` it is a call which gets handles by an `Respondent`. But where is the *escalate* part?

Currently the call has an fixed level which means that the caller can choose if he wants to talk with an `Respondent` or an `Manager`. Instead the caller should only allowed to call a `Respondent` and the `Respondent` has to delegate the call to a `Manager`.

## `main` in its own Class

I would create a new class for the `main` which is currently in `CallCenter`. This would reduce the complexity and makes a step farther to make the components more reusable.

## Encapsulation

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)):

> Encapsulation, in object-oriented programming, is the bundling of data with the methods that operate on that data, or the restricting of direct access to some of an objects components. Encapsulation **is used to hide the values or state of a structured data object inside a class, preventing unauthorized parties' direct access to them**.

On closer inspection, all fields have no access modifier, which means that they are all [package-private(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/java/accesscontrol.html) at the moment so other classes can access them directly.

As an example we could look into `Call`:

> ```
> class Call {
>    /* ... */
>
>    int id;
>    int durationInSeconds;
>    int level;
>
>    /* ... */
> }
> ```

Now lets focus on `durationInSeconds` which gets used directly by `Respondent`, `Manager` and
 `Director`:

> ```java
> Thread.sleep(call.durationInSeconds * 1000);
> ```

The goal would be to make all fields `private`, like:

```java
class Call {
    /* ... */

    private int id;
    private int durationInSeconds;
    private int level;

    /* ... */
}
```

## Static Variables

> ```java
> public class CallCenter {
>
>  static BlockingQueue<Call> respondantQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(20);
>  static BlockingQueue<Call> directorQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(20);
>
>  /* ... */
> }
> ```

Imagine you want to open a new call center. With the declaration `static` the old and the new call center divide the queues and with the current implementation the call can not be differentiated between old and new call center: **The new call center could handle calls from the old call center**..

## Useless Variables

To identify a `Call` it has an `id`, but the `id` never gets accessed and is only in the `Call#toString`.
After we delete `id` we will see that `idCounter` is useless too..

If the `id` would not be useless it would be good to use it in an `equal`-Method and move the
`idCounter` to a component which creates the `Call` - for example the `CallCenter` or a new
class like a `CallFactory`.

## Business Logic in Constructor

> ```java
> Arrays.asList(new Director("The Director"));
> ```

Without knowing the code, I would not expect, that the line above executes the business logic of the
director.

Additionally the constructor becomes a high level of complexity. When we look into `Respondant`s
constructor: it has 6 levels of indentation!

## Some OOP

I think a suitable design pattern would be the [Observer Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer).

Every time the `CallCenter` receives a `Call` it can inform the employees.

Comment: `When the call is of level 0 it is a call which gets handles by an Respondent. But where is the escalate part?` -> It is when the call is not level `0`.

Comment: I added a paragraph to make it clearer.
In short: The `Respondent` never delegates the call. The `Manager` only receives a call, when the caller calls with the level 1. But actually the caller should always call with level 0.

Comment: Chain of responsibility is the design pattern here. Not observer

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/202690/call-center-escalation-excercise-using-chain-of-responsibility-pattern

Comment: @Roman  But actually the caller should always call with level 0. -> No.

Comment: @KorayTugay yes, that what i'm talking about. The caller calls with `0` and imagine there is no free `Respondent`. Will the level be increased? No..

Comment: @Roman It will not be, and that is expected by the requirements. "An incoming phone call must be allocated to a respondent who is free.". No free respondants -> No one answers your call.

Comment: @Gilad yes, the chain of responsibility is correct for the shipping part, but the observer could be used to inform a `respondent` instead of the `respondent` having to look for a new call every second.

Comment: @KorayTugay From your task: _If the respondent cannot handle the call, they must escalate it to a manager._

Comment: @Roman That is exactly what my implementation is doing. Anyway, this is becoming a ping-pong, lets agree we do not agree.

Comment: @Roman A respondant is not looking for a new call every second. Respondants pick up calls from queue.

Comment: @KorayTugay Your `Respondent` calls in a `while`-loop`CallCenter.respondantQueue.take()` - this means he is asking every time for a new call.

Comment: @Roman `CallCenter.respondantQueue.take()` is a blocking call, he is waiting for a call, not asking for anything, and not every second. Anyway I will not continue with discussion as it is jumping to something else everytime. I suggest you to study the code a little more in detail.